# Typescript compiler build errors from Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, visual-studio-2015, angular, tsc

I set up a basic web application with Angular2 and Typescript. On build of the solution, I get many errors like : `TS2304: Cannot find name Promise` and these are coming from inside the `node_modules` folder. Visual Studio 2015 won't take `tsconfig.json` file into account so I cannot tell it to exclude certain folders either. So, what can I do to make it work other than reverting to using Visual Studio Code instead of Visual Studio 2015?

Comment: Try updating to the [1.8 beta of TypeScript](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2016/01/28/announcing-typescript-1-8-beta/). It lets you override your VS project's compile settings with a `tsconfig.json` file.

Comment: @JoeClay Updated to latest TS but still looking into node_modules folder and emitting lots of errors.

Comment: Can you post your tsconfig.json file?